# replace rebuilded module JAR in the EAR (Maven2 project)

Tags: maven-2, jar, replace, ear, rebuild

During the development time I'm iteratively rebuilding some modules of my project. Rebuilding resulting ear-project gets a huge amount of time. If there is a way allowing to rebuild only jar file of changed module and then replace this jar in resulting EAR then it could reduce build time and accelerate development process.

So questions: Is there any maven plugin allowing to do partial module rebuilding and replacing jars in ear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use the `-pl` or `--projects` option (requires Maven 2.1+, see [Maven Tips and Tricks: Advanced Reactor Options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) for more details)? Something like that:

```
mvn --projects your-jar,your-ear install
```

This might speed up things.